# Replace parenthesis and newline, with parenthesis

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I want to remove the newline if the last character before it was an opening parenthesis. So this:

```
one
two(
three
```

Should become:

```
one
two(three
```

I tried somethings with awk and sed, but cannot get it right:

```
 awk '/\($/ {printf "%s ", $0} {print; next}'
 sed 's/($/(/g'
```

Comment: Using `getline` just do `awk '/\($/{ if (getline nextl >0 ) $0=$0""nextl }1' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `gnu sed` you can do:

```
sed '/($/{N;s/\n//;}' file
```

```
one
two(three
```

Or using `awk`:

```
awk '/\($/{p=$0; getline; printf "%s", p} 1' file
```

```
one
two(three
```

Comment: That's the winner. Originally I just though we were removing the `'('`, but you got part 2 of the question nailed.

Comment: Tried both, smooth like silk. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

using awk:

regex: `\(\n`
replace with: `(`

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS=""}{gsub(/\(\n/,     "(",$0); print $0}' file_name
                          ^ regex    ^ replace
```

It prints:

```
one
two(three
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/^t/{printf $0}NR==1;END{print ""}' file

one
two(three
```